# Calcium and nitric oxide: does a numerical relationship exist?

Tags: neuroscience, biophysics, synapses, calcium

Currently, I am trying to understand how nitric oxide and calcium are related during the production of the former (I am not a biologist nor a chemist, so my knowledge about these topics is very poor). I would like to know if there are some papers or experiments that present a model (or, at least, some numerical data) that relate the concentration of nitric oxide with the concentration of calcium.

I've read somewhere that one of the effects of nitric oxide in synaptic transmission is the reduction of calcium influx, but how does it happen quantitatively? I've started my research considering the model reported [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/99/16/10831.full) where NMDA is assumed to be main calcium source so that the time derivative of calcium concentration is directly related to the NMDA current. Now, I think this model should be slightly modified if I would consider the effects of nitric oxide; I've found a model that describes how nitric oxide synthesis occurs, but what is missing for me is the link between calcium concentration and nitric oxide concentration.

Comment: It seems that you want to have a look at neuronal nitric oxide synthases. Not an expert on this but there seem to be some references in this paper:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3514612/pdf/fncir-06-00082.pdf

Comment: @vkehayas Thank you for your reply. I will read the paper you cited hoping to understand something more about the topic. However, at first glance the paper explains detailly all the biological aspects of nNOS but I don't see how nitric oxide is related to calcium. I will check later.